# CSS hover at level row

Tags: html, css

At this table, I apply a CSS
example from here
http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx
and the example
https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="gvMain2" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;"> 
    <tr class="GridViewScrollHeader">
        <th>StandardCost</th>
        <th>ListPrice</th>
        <th>SafetyStockLevel</th>
        <th>SellStartDate</th>
        <th>SellEndDate</th>
        <th>ModifiedDate</th>
        <th>ProductID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>ReorderPoint</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridViewScrollItem">
        <td>747</td>
        <td>HL Mountain Frame - Black, 38</td>
        <td>FR-M94B-38</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>2.68</td>
        <td>739.0410</td>
        <td>1349.6000</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>7/1/2001 12:00:00 AM</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>3/11/2004 10:01:36 AM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS section Header ok assign the color

```
.GridViewScrollHeader TH,
.GridViewScrollHeader TD {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: palegoldenrod;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    cursor:default;
}
```

CSS section Item at level TD assign the color and border, and the cell change color when the event TD:hover is triggered

```
.GridViewScrollItem TD {
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    /*background-color: lemonchiffon;*/
    color: blue;
    background-color: gray;
    /*cursor: pointer;*/
}

/* this work and change color at cell level */
.GridViewScrollItem TD:hover {
     background-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

CSS hover at level row ??
at the line, TR level does not trigger the hover event, as if there were no instructions, certainly my error, even though it seems correct to refer to TR.

```
/* this section not have effect 
- the cursor not change form
- the background color not change
*/
.GridViewScrollItem TR {
   background-color: #b8d1f3;    
}

.GridViewScrollItem TR:hover {
   /* background-color: #00C080FF; */
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: So basically, `td` `background-color` doesn't change when hovering over `tr`?

Answer (score 3):

The row color does change, but under the colored TD. So apply the effect directly to the column with:

```
.GridViewScrollItem:hover TD {
   /* background-color: #00C080FF; */
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

In addition, `.GridViewScrollItem` is the actual TR you mention, so basically your original CSS rule said:

```
tr tr:hover {};
```

Working codepen example:
https://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/LOjMNW